# How to parse HTTP status codes in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-status-codes

I'm using an API library in Node that doesn't return the status code of the HTTP response. However, it does return the response headers, which look like this:

```
{ ...
  status: '200 OK',
  ... }
```

Is there any Node library I can use to parse the status code from the returned object's status? Will a crude `+res.status.slice(0, 3)` do?

---

**EDIT:** [Link](https://github.com/pksunkara/octonode/blob/master/src/octonode/repo.coffee#L312) to the library.

Comment: `parseInt('200 OK', 10);` will yield the integer 200, which I assume you want but it has the drawbacks that you're now relying on the fact that the status codes need to start with the actual error code and not the text, otherwise just `status.split(' ')[0]`.

Comment: I'd prefer a simple regexp: `status.match(/\d+/)`

Comment: @HenrikAndersson That's OK. Awesome solution, thanks!

Comment: @HenrikAndersson: if the status code isn't in the first three characters then it's not a status code.

Comment: @JulianReschke I was just pointing out a potential pitfall, is all. :)

Comment: @HenrikAnderson: why would it be a pitfall when parsing an invalid response fails?

Comment: @JulianReschke Because parsing would not fail audibly but just produce a NaN, which you can pass around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All HTTP status codes have 3 digits, so your slice example will work. However, I would personally just split on space:

```
var code = status.split(' ')[0];
```